# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Gamma(n)/n^n$ demonstrably irrational?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

**The Question**

What do we know about  $$\xi(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z)}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+z-1)}{n^n}= \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x\ln x)^z} $$

Specifically, what can be said about $\xi$  regarding it's rationality at integer values?
Obviously, they're surely all irrational(because a number plucked from the reals should be irrational) but of course we are interested in demonstrably irrational.

- Is $\xi(z)$ irrational for (some) integer $z$?
- Are infinitely many $\xi(z)$ irrational? Is atleast one?

**Exposition**
I'm not sure that these thoughts will prove helpful in making any claims but here goes.

Generally we may write
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(-x\ln x\right)^{k}}{\left(1+x\ln x\right)^{z}}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\left(1+x\ln x\right)^{z}}dx-\sum_{n=1}^{k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\left(-x\ln x\right)^{k-n}}{\left(1+x\ln x\right)^{z-1}}dx$$
But in the case $z=1$ this is simply

$$\int_0^1 \frac{(-x \ln x)^k}{1+x\ln x}dx=\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n)}{n^n}$$

And $(-x \ln x)$ is maximally $1/e$ so we have some of the conditions which resemble Beuker's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(s)$ for $s \le 3$. That is we have an integral that we can manipulate for bounds on the tail of our series. But this type of argument works for small values of $s$ because the growth rate of  $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2,\dots n)^s$  can be overcome but of course $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2, \dots n^n)$ grows even more rapidly.

On the other hand, maybe $\xi$ is better behaved than $\zeta$ in the sense that $
\xi$  is an [entire function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755983/show-that-the-series-defines-and-entire-function-sum-n-1-infty-zz1-cd?noredirect=1).

$\xi(2)$ is asked about on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185875/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-fracnnnis-irrational?noredirect=1) and crossposted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277969/is-sum-n-1-infty-fracnnn-rational?_gl=1*h2u0p8*_ga*MTk0NjgwODUwOS4xNjg1MTQ0MTA3*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY4NTU5ODU0MS45LjAuMTY4NTU5ODU0MS4wLjAuMA..) There is a pretty continued fraction form there  $$\xi(2)=\frac{1}{2+\underset{n=2}{\overset{\infty}{K} }\frac{-n^{2n-1}}{n^n+(n+1)^n}}=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{-8}{13+\frac{-243}{91+\frac{-16384}{881+\frac{-1953125}{10901+\frac{-362797056}{164305+\frac{...}{...}}}}}}}$$
I'm hopeful that this continued fraction can be generalized to $\xi(z)$.

Comment: To obtain a CF, you can start with $$
\xi (z) = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 2}^\infty  {\prod\limits_{k = 2}^n {\left( {1 + \frac{{z - 2}}{k}} \right)\left( {1 - \frac{1}{k}} \right)^{k - 1} } } .
$$

Comment: *Is at least one* is covered by the first question, I guess.